# Non-infinite paging

Tags: android, android-paging

I'm using the newest [Paging 3 library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview) and trying to implement non-infinite paging by using `PagingSource` class which executes requests to my API.

What do I want to do?

When the user scrolls to the end of `RecyclerView` list instead of automatically getting the next chunk of data a next-button should be shown. By clicking on it `PagingSource.load` method should be invoked as if it would be in case of infinite scrolling.

This is how my `PagingSource` class looks like:

```
class LiveTickerPagingSource(
        private val service: LiveTickerService
) : PagingSource<Int, LiveTickerEntry>() {
    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, LiveTickerEntry> {
        val position = params.key ?: STARTING_PAGE_INDEX
        return try {
            val response = service.getEntries()//params.loadSize
            val entries = response.items
            LoadResult.Page(
                    data = entries,
                    prevKey = null,
                    nextKey = null
            )
        } catch (exception: IOException) {
            LoadResult.Error(exception)
        } catch (exception: HttpException) {
            LoadResult.Error(exception)
        }
    }

}
```

ViewModel:

```
class LiveTickerModuleViewModel(private val repository: LiveTickerModuleRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private var liveTickerResult: Flow<PagingData<LiveTickerEntry>>? = null

    fun getEntries(): Flow<PagingData<LiveTickerEntry>> {
        val newResult: Flow<PagingData<LiveTickerEntry>> = repository.getLiveTickerEntriesStream()
            .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
        liveTickerResult = newResult

        return newResult
    }

}
```

Repository:

```
class LiveTickerModuleRepository(private val service: LiveTickerModuleService) {

    fun getLiveTickerEntriesStream(): Flow<PagingData<LiveTickerEntry>> {
        return Pager(
                config = PagingConfig(pageSize = NETWORK_PAGE_SIZE, initialLoadSize = NETWORK_PAGE_SIZE, enablePlaceholders = false),
                pagingSourceFactory = { LiveTickerModulePagingSource(service) }
        ).flow

    }

    companion object {
        private const val NETWORK_PAGE_SIZE = 3
    }
}
```

And lastly Fragment:

```
class LiveTickerModuleFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentLiveTickerModuleBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel: LiveTickerModuleViewModel
    private var liveTickerJob: Job? = null
    private val adapter by lazy { LiveTickerModuleAdapter() }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, Injection.provideViewModelFactory())
            .get(LiveTickerModuleViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = FragmentLiveTickerModuleBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        initAdapter()
        getLiveTickerEntries()
        return binding.root
    }

    private fun getLiveTickerEntries() {
        liveTickerJob?.cancel()
        liveTickerJob = lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.getEntries().collectLatest {
                adapter.submitData(it)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun initAdapter() {
        binding.list.adapter = adapter
        adapter.addLoadStateListener { loadState ->
            val sourceAppend = loadState.source.append
            val sourcePrepend = loadState.source.prepend
            val errorState = sourceAppend as? LoadState.Error
                ?: sourcePrepend as? LoadState.Error
            val endOfPaginationReached = errorState?.endOfPaginationReached
        }
    }
}
```

I was using [this codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-paging/#0) as my reference, which is based on infinite scrolling. I'm thankful for any kind of explanation. It doesn't necessarily have to be code.

Answer (score 0):

This is supported, but you may find Paging adds more complexity than necessary if you don't need incremental loading.

For a static list you can simply use:

```
PagingDataAdapter.submitData(PagingData.from(myList)
```

Otherwise, if you're loading from a resource, you can implement a `PagingSource` which returns a `LoadResult.Page` with `nextKey` and `prevKey` set to `null`. You'll need to construct a `Pager`, then observe the `PagingData` stream to submit to `PagingDataAdapter` with `adapter.submitData(PagingData)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I forgot to mention that I'm fetching data from an API. I managed to construct a `Pager` with the mentioned parameters. I'm guessing I need to invoke `PagingDataAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver` method in order to observe data changes?

Comment: You want PagingDataAdapter.submitData(PagingData).